# How to get data from excel file to datatable in c#

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, .net-4.0

I am using Epplus library to get data from Excel file to datatable by using following code.The following code will work for normal excel file which contains first line as columns and rest all rows.But my excel file is typical structured one which is shown as
[image: typical excel]

Here 9th row should be the actual columns of the datatable and rest all rows.One more twist here is column `Description` value is (first column value)+second column , for example first row is `(Dess)Dess model11` , then second is `(Dess)Dess model12`.So `Dess` and `Cess` is common factor for column `Description` .How to move these values to data table in c# ?

Comment: To read the excel there are plenty of working examples online also you could write your own using `TextFieldParser` this is part of the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.File.IO.TextParser` I parse Excel files every day writing my own quick and simple Parser ConvertingCSV2DataTable. there is also `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` notice the Aliasing.. I you want that because the key work `Application` will conflict with your normal apps you can name your alias anything you want

Comment: @MethodMan i don't want to use any unmanaged dll,i want to use EPPPLUS library ,if any one can suggest a logic here it would be greate

Comment: I don't have the code at the moment but I remember that EPPlus have the posibility to read Cell Range Values and Merge Cells. Maybe this will help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/680421/Create-Read-Edit-Advance-Excel-Report-in#3

Comment: If somebody can post code snippet,it would be great